# trying to write a paper on mac os x and win xp system scheduling cant find info

Tags: macos, windows-xp, scheduling

im trying to write a paper on mac os 10 and windows xp system scheduling but cant find any information on the web can anyone suggest websites ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help for Mac [Mac OSX Internals](http://osxbook.com/)